# draw rectangle and label it by drag lines around in html

Tags: css, html

i want to draw something like this in html.is that possible in html that i can label the rectangle ? i think may be by using `<hr>` ?

[image]

at the moment  i have just draw a rectangle

here is the code

```
<div style="width:150px;height:80px;border:1px solid #000;">This is a rectangle!</div>
```

how can i draw lines around it and then label it

Comment: You can use embedded SVG image for this.

Comment: Might take a look at [CSS shapes](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: you can make this having different divs and using positions. But some kind of hard coding it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will give you the output you want but this is a kind of hard coding.

```
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;top:20px;">a</div>
<div class="hLine" style="width:150px;height:1px;background:#000;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:20px;"></div>
<div style="width:150px;height:80px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;position:relative;left:-5px;">This is a rectangle!</div>
<div class="hLine" style="width:150px;height:1px;background:#000;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:20px;left:-10px;"></div>
<div style="display:inline-block; position:relative;top:20px;">b</div>
<div class="vLine"style="height:40px;width:1px;background:#000;position:relative;left:230px;"></div>
<div style="position:relative;left:230px;">c</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the lines and labels with `pseudo elements` and `data attributes` using just 2 elements

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzDtQ/7/)**

### Markup:

```
<div data-label1="a" data-label2="b">
    <span data-label3="c">XYZ Pty Ltd</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div
{
    width:150px;
    height:80px;
    border:1px solid #000; 
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 100px;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
}
span
{
  padding: 10px 20px;    
  display: inline-block;
}
div:before, div:after
{
    content: attr(data-label1);
    position:absolute;
    left: -50px;
    top: 40px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 1px;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #000;
    text-align:left;
    font-size: 18px;  
}
div:after
{
    content: attr(data-label2);
    right:-50px;
    left: auto;
    text-align: right;
}
span:after
{
    content: attr(data-label3);
    position:absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin: auto;
    padding-top:100px;
    top:20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For line segments don’t use

```
<hr>
```

because its width is dependent on the width of the parent container. So in order to set its width you need to introduce a div to restrict its width. so instead of creating two elements. create the line with just div by keeping its height:0px, and width: desired width. you got your horizontal line segment. If you want a vertical line then keep width zero and height the desired amount.

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using normal HTML and css or using HTML5 Canvas,I am giving you with html and css

http://jsbin.com/IlArOTE/1/edit